# Commerce product and variation entity APIs are taking lot of execution time

Tags: drupal-commerce, drupal-10

I have recently upgraded from Drupal 9.5 to Drupal 10.0.0.
What I have noticed is commerce product & variation APIs are taking a lot of time for execution, it nearly takes around 11 to 13 seconds to load even 1 variation.
In the previous Drupal 9.5 version, the output would take nearly max 2sec.

Due to this, it is affecting the further flows of the project.

Any idea/ suggestion on how to reduce the execution time?

Thanks in advance!

Not sure but adding code related to caching will work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.